# Dynamically added checked attributes C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm new in C# ASP .Net. I've a problem like this:
I've data from database like this:

```
button_id | button_access
-------------------------
btnSearch | true
btnClear  | true
btnAdd    | false
btnSave   | false
```

in my view:

```
@data [data from database]
...
@foreach (chk in data) {
  <input name="btnSearch" type="checkbox" value="@chk.button_id" {???} />
}
...
```

I think, in `{???}` I have to insert a condition like:

```
IF (chk.buttonAccess) {
   //Code to write attribute checked
}
```

What should I filled in `{???}` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@(chk.button_access ? "checked" : "")
```